# Search string and return matching substring MongoDB

Tags: mongodb-query

I am working on a golang project with database MongoDB. I have a collection with following records:

```
[
    {
        "_id": 1,
        "vals": [
            "110",
            "2211"
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": 1,
        "vals": [
            "Abcd",
            "102"
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to perform a search like if I pass "11001" then 1st record will return. But I have not found any solution to do the same. I have tried the following query:

```
db.getCollection('ColName').find({"vals":{"$regex": "^11001", "$options": "i"}})
```

Characters that are saved in db are less that I passed in the search. If I pass the "110" or "11" then it will gives the result, but my requirement is different I have full string and need to match with 2,3, or 4 characters.

Comment: `^11((0)?0)?$` or `^(11|110|1100)$` or three separate `find` statements (without regular expressions) will match with `11`, `110`, `1100`, but not with `111`, `11002`

Comment: The search string `11001` obviously should be truncated to 1100 and transformed to one RegExp or three substrings `11`, `110`, `1100` if matching with 5 symbols isn't required

Comment: @bartolo-otrit  Thanks for your suggestion. Right now I have break the string into 11, 110,1100 and match with in operator.

Answer (score 0):

It is about regex.

```
db.getCollection('ColName').find({"vals":{"$regex": "^110(01)?", "$options": "i"}})
```

will work for you.
"?" in regex means match 0 or 1.

Comment: This will not work for me. because I have to pass full string within the query and match only the first 2,3 or 4 character.